# iterator implementation

Tags: c++, insert, iterator

when implementing insert function in general `pair<iterator,bool>` is returned is stl library
I am implementing stl -like class .can I return in the pair an iterator as local variable i.e.

```
itartor it;//init it
return pair<iterator,bool>(it,true);
```

or should I dynamically allocate iterator i.e.:

```
itartor it = new iterator;
return pair<iterator,bool>(*it,true);
```

Comment: The fact that one version contains the word `new` should tip you off which one is wrong :-)

Comment: On a second reading, the second version is outright insane: you just end up making a *copy* of the dynamically allocated iterator and return that copy by value. Madness. (And it doesn't actually compile.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the first option. There is no reason whatsoever for the second, since you are dereferencing the pointer anyway. And leaking memory:

```
iterator it = new iterator;
return pair<iterator,bool>(*it,true);
                             ^ dereference here -> memory leak.
```

Standard library iterators are designed to be passed by value. You should make sure your iterators are cheap to copy, and avoid all dynamic memory management pitfalls.

Comment: I think "prefer" is a totally inadequate word here. "Unconditionally must" is closer to the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Return the iterator by value. Iterators are designed to be light-weight and copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever return dynamically allocated content unless you know what you're doing (and you're able to handle it properly). As such, go with the first one.

Given the fact you can't even return a pointer here, this won't work (in your code example you'd still create a copy of the allocated object/memory).